# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'role')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to give special role to admin using a middleware customRole which checks the default role of user in the database and provide special administration for the user with admin role.

My controller code for userController is:

```
const User = require('../models/User')
//Other requires are present but not needed for this function.
.
.
.

exports.adminAllUser = BigPromise(async(req, res, next) => {
    const users = await User.find()

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true, 
        users,
    })
})
```

My middleware code for user is:

```
const User = require('../models/User')
const CustomError = require('../utils/customError')
.
.
.
exports.customRole = (...roles) => {
    return(req, res, next) => {
        if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
            return next(new CustomError('You are not allowed for this resource', 403))
        }
        next()
    }
}
```

My user route is /admin/users and I am passing 3 functions to give power to admin when logged in.

```
const { adminAllUser } = require("../controllers/userController")
const { isLoggedIn, customRole } = require('../middleware/user')
.
.
.
router.route('/admin/users').get(isLoggedIn, customRole('admin'), adminAllUser)
```

The error I am receiving whenever I am giving a GET request to /admin/users with admin role:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'role')
    at C:\Users\****\Login API\middleware\user.js:24:38
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] C:\Users\****\Login API\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\****\Login API\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at C:\Users\****\Login API\middleware\user.js:19:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you debug your code you will find out that no value is passing into that role.

debug here `if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {`

Comment: I have console.logged it and showing undefined. May I know what will be the reason for not passing this `req.user.role` value? It is there in the database, but couldn't retrieve it.

Comment: I think it is the spread operator not working correctly.

Comment: Can you please give me a code to avoid using spread operator in this case?
I am just a beginner referring videos for learning, my instructor done like this and he didn't get any errors.